# show nothing after installed yii2, in web folder

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2

Im new in yii2.0. After installed yii2.

i try to open locahost/yiitest/web Should be congratulation page, but page just show "run();"

web/index.php

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Can you tell me, whats my mistake.

i use ubuntu.

thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (_"why isn't this code working?"_) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: im haven't do anything after installed. I just want to show congratulations page

Comment: you call the link/url with the browser  eg: locahost/yiitest/web/index.php ?

Comment: of course nope. just localhost/yiitest/web. http://i65.tinypic.com/2rw9c7q.png

Comment: I solved that. my mistake when instalation php or something else. Just remove that. and then reinstall correctly.